# How to add a key/value to the HashMap?

Tags: python, class

```py
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_length = 8
        self.max_load_factor = 0.8
        self.length = 0
        self.map = [None] * self.max_length

    def get(self, key, default):
        value = dict.get(key, default)
        return value  # returns the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else
                      # default. If default is not given, it defaults to none.

    def set(self, key, value):
        #need to add the key value pair into the hashmap
        #if self.max_load_factor >= .8:
            #refresh the map into a map double the capacity
```

So I was able to put in the `get()` method for my hashmap, that was relatively simple (which returns the value for the key if the key is in the dictionary, etc, …) But how do I add a key value pair into the hashmap itself?

Could someone point me in the correct direction? Do I need to add it to the `self.map` instance?

Comment: Just use a `dict`.  That's Python's builtin hash table type.

Comment: A dictionary object is python equivalent of hashmaps in java, complete with exception handling and all that jazz - they're easy to use as well! You're better of using a python dictionary instead of writing your own hashmap class. Unless you're wanting to write a hashmap for a specific reason, which i would love to hear

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how you're trying to use this, and I don't see you define `dict` anywhere. But I think I see what you wanted, and something like

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return self.dict.get(key, default)

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.dict[key] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hm = HashMap()
    hm.set('test', 'hello, world')
    print(hm.get('test'))
```

should do it (and outputs)

```
hello, world
```

Comment: Seems weird and over the top to reinvent the wheel using a wheel that does less than a wheel can do.

Comment: @Jab I don't disagree with you. I just answered the question.